# eclipse creating new android application project

Tags: android, eclipse

When I try to create new android application project in eclipse I generate another project named `appcompat_v7` i tried several times and it is still same. Odd thing is both have error because I can see a red `!`.

How to avoid auto generating this project and also avoid the `!` on the main folder

Comment: Leave eclipse and try android studio

Comment: why dont you use the Android studio :)

Comment: make sure that your output directory is clean.

Comment: @kgandroid because I spend so many hours tying to download a plugin in eclipse. I tried deleting the auto generated project and now i get error in `res` folder

Comment: now you have to waste another several hours resolving that issue....so my suggestion is use android studio which is now recommend by google itself

Comment: **Eclipse for Android in 2016?** It's not a sin but no longer maintained and that might cause you extra pain resolving things.

Comment: last question could i use android studio to do cordova ? does it have plug in for nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create a new project in eclipse make sure that your minimum API version is 14.Then it will not create the appcompact folder.

[image]

Comment: my minimum is API 8. but this works thanks. would you suggest to use android studio?

Comment: So you have to select minimum api 14 to avoid being created the appcompact folder

Comment: would you suggest to use android studio?

Comment: Yes...currently Android studio is the best platform to develop android apps.